# TS/JS - Get "value" from an Array of Objects if a Property of an Object from the Array matches another Property from a separate Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter, find

**THE PROBLEM:**

I have an array of Objects. And a currentObject, that I currently am viewing. I want to get the value from a Property that comes from the Array of Objects, if 2 other properties match.

Here is the Array, simplified:

```
ARRAY = [{
  id: 1,
  metadata: {author: "Company1"}
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  metadata: {author: "Company2"}
 }
```

Here is the Object, simplified:

```
OBJECT = {
 name: "Something
 templateId: 2
}
```

So, basically, I want to return, the `metdata.author` information, if the `ARRAY.id`, matches the `OBJECT.templateId`..

Here is the code I wrote..

```
const getAuthorInfo = (connTemplates: ARRAY[], currentConn: ITEM_OBJECT) => {
  connTemplates.find((connTemplate: ARRAY_ITEM_OBJECT) => connTemplate.id === currentConn.templateId);
};

console.log('Author Info:', connection); // This though returns the OBJECT, not the ARRAY_ITEM
```

Any ideas, on how to make this work? I tried to `filter` as well, with the same condition, but that returned `undefined`, when I called it in my ReactComponent.

Comment: Provided that your `return` from your `getAuthorInfo`, you'll get an object from your `ARRAY`. Then use `.metadata.author` to gets author

Comment: It returns the object. Not the object from the Array. So, the info isn't there.

Comment: You are running `.find()` on `connTemplates`, which is your array. You can only get `undefined` or an object from your array in return, I can't see how you are getting `OBJECT` as the return ?

Answer (score 0):

is this what you need?

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  metadata: { author: "Company1" }
},
{
  id: 2,
  metadata: { author: "Company2" }
}]

const obj = {
  name: "Something",
  templateId: 2
}



function getAuthorInfo(arr, obj) {
  const arrItem = arr.find(item => item.id === obj.templateId)
  return arrItem.metadata.author
}

console.log(getAuthorInfo(arr, obj))
```

Comment: Reutrns the OBJECT. Not the object from the Array. So the info isn't there..

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path:

```
const result = arr.find(f => f.id == obj.templateId).metadata.author;
```

```js
    const arr = [{
      id: 1,
      metadata: {author: "Company1"}
     },
     {
      id: 2,
      metadata: {author: "Company2"}
     }]
    
     const obj = {
      name: "Something",
      templateId: 2
     }
    
    
    const result = arr.find(f => f.id == obj.templateId);
    
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: I think he wants to drill down more into the object and get the actual author...

Comment: I guess I was wrong... based on the response to my answer... I'm not sure I understand the question...